# Python Stripe: 'module' object has no attribute 'Charge'

Tags: python, stripe-payments, attributeerror

I have installed **[Stripe](https://stripe.com)** on my MacOSX Mavericks Macbook Pro (python 2.7) using

- pip install --index-url https://code.stripe.com --upgrade stripe
- easy_install --index-url https://code.stripe.com --upgrade stripe
- python setup.py install

but I always get the following error message:

```
$ sudo python stripe.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stripe.py", line 1, in <module>
    import stripe
  File "/Users/sebastian/Desktop/stripe.py", line 7, in <module>
    resp = stripe.Charge.create(
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Charge'
```

when I try to execute the following script:

```
import stripe

stripe.api_key = 'my_test_secret_key'

resp = stripe.Charge.create(
    amount=200,
    currency='usd',
    card={
        'number': '4242424242424242',
        'exp_month': 10,
        'exp_year': 2014
    },
    description='customer@gmail.com'
)
```

Comment: You called your script `stripe.py`; what do you think Python finds first when importing `stripe` now?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have another file that is called `stripe.py`, so this file is getting imported instead of the `stripe` library.

Here's how you fix this:

- Rename your `stripe.py` file to something different
- Remove `stripe.pyc` if it exists (mind the `c`)

---

Said file is on your desktop: `/Users/sebastian/Desktop/stripe.py`.

Comment: Ok everything clear now ... it is already working as expected

Comment: This answer is the best answer, and I think it's the only right answer in this case; `Charge` was always in the stripe API and the OP clearly had filename ambiguity issues. But I'm cross-linking to [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66456420/1175496), which explains my stripe Python library /version is simply out of date: `"'module' object has no attribute 'SetupIntent'"`