# AttributeError: module 'stripe' has no attribute 'PaymentIntent'

Tags: python, api, mobile, stripe-payments

I have installed Stripe python module (1.70.0) and wanted to create a PaymentIntent to charge for mobile. But fail to do so.

```
import stripe
stripe.api_key = "sk_test_XXXXXXXXX"
stripe.PaymentIntent.create(
  amount=1099,
  currency='usd',
  payment_method_types=['card'],
)
```

AttributeError: module 'stripe' has no attribute 'PaymentIntent'. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: update to 1.84.2

Comment: Similar issue for me: `"'module' object has no attribute 'SetupIntent'"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Version 1.70.0 is from 2017 and doesn't support PaymentIntents(which was added in 1.84.0). You should update to the latest version of the library.

https://github.com/stripe/stripe-python/wiki/Migration-guide-for-v2

https://github.com/stripe/stripe-python/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#1700---2017-10-23
https://github.com/stripe/stripe-python/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#1840---2018-06-29

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error, but in my case my error was that I named the django app with the same name as the stripe library.

A basic mistake but one that can happen to a newbie.